# экспорт русского текста из pdf документа в python

Tags: python, pdf

коллеги!
Я пытаюсь достать текст из pdf. Вот этот документ http://voeikovmgo.ru/images/stories/publications/2020/ejegodnik_zagr_atm_2019.pdf

Мне надо из пятой страницы получить  текст:

```
pl = open('C:/ejegodnik_zagr_atm_2019.pdf', 'rb')
plread = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pl)
getpage = plread.getPage(4)
text = getpage.extractText()
print(text)
```

в качестве результата я получаю

```
'5 \n \n \n 89 \n 131 \n 90 \n 132 \n. 91 \n 133 \n 92 \n 134 \n 93 \n 135 \n 94 \n 136 \n 95 \n 137 \n 96 \n 138 \n 98 \n 139 \n. 99 \n 140 \n 100 \n 142 \n 101 \n\n 143 \n 102 \n 144 \n 103 \n 145 \n 104 \n 146 \n 105 \n 147 \n 106 \n \n 148 \n 108 \n 149 \n 109 \n 150 \n 110 \n-\n \n 151 \n-\n 111 \n 112 \n 152 \n 112 \n 153 \n 114 \n 154 \n 115 \n 155 \n 116 \n 156 \n 117 \n 157 \n 118 \n 158 \n 119 \n 159 \n 120 \n 160 \n 121 \n 161 \n-\n 122 \n 162 \n 124 \n-\n \n 163 \n 125 \n 164 \n 126 \n 165 \n 127 \n 166 \n 129 \n-\n 167 \n 130 \n 168 \n \n \n \n 184 \n 205 \n 187 \n 207 \n 189 \n-\n 209 \n 191 \n 212 \n 194 \n-\n 214 \n 197  217 \n 200 \n 219 \n 202 '
```

Моя задача - получить также текст на русском.Как решить данную задачу?

Comment: PDF - очень сложный формат для извлечения данных напрямую. Иногда везёт, текст располагается как надо и экспортируется без проблем, но отнюдь не всегда. Возможно, Вам стоит задуматься об OCR, распознавании по картинке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде как PyPDF2 плохо работает с кириллицей. Можно попробовать [pdfminer](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
import pdfminer.high_level
text = pdfminer.high_level.extract_text('C:/ejegodnik_zagr_atm_2019.pdf', page_numbers = [4])
print(text)
```

В аргументе `page_numbers` передаём список страниц, текст из которых хотим извлчеь.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте:

```
print(text.encode("latin-1").decode('cp1251'))
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Согласен с предыдущим высказыванием. Сейчас ответ немного не по теме вопроса

Comment: @Oleg, а вы пробовали этот код применить к строке из вопроса? В данном случае он ничего не изменит.